# Migrating Google OpenID to OpenID Connect for google apps domain OpenIDs

Tags: google-oauth, google-openid

I'm migrating from Google OpenID to OpenID Connect and needing to get back the OpenID of the logged in user's OpenID when logging in to Google using OpenID Connect. As spepcified in google documentation, I pass the openid.realm parameter that matches exactly with the openid.realm that I used with OpenID authentication, and I'm getting back the value in openid_id. I'm finding that for google apps domain users, the OpenIDs that I have are of format:

http:// <google apps domain> /openid?id=xxxx

whereas the value returned in openid_id are always of format:

https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xyz

Is there any way to retrieve the domain format OpenIDs?

Regards.
LT

Comment: Try it out at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and publish your findings here

Comment: I'm not sure how I can even test this in the playground. AS per https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID, to test this you need to add openid.realm parameter to OpenID Connect authentication request and you get back the extra openid_id value in the response. The problem as I mentioned is that the openid_id returned is always the google accounts OpenID and not the domain format OpenID, which is what we have as we authenticate OpenID using RP discovery of the form https: // www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=<google apps domain> rather than https: // www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to get the domain format OpenId returned. In addition to passing in the optional parameter openid.realm in the authentication request, I needed to pass in the optional parameter hd set to the domain. When this is done, then the OpenId returned is the domain format which matches up with what we have saved.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#hd-param

LT